Do the Carrier and Delivery Customization Function APIs in Shopify Conflict
Background:
Checkout.liquid is being deprecated in August in favor of using Checkout Extensibility. One of the customizations we had in checkout.liquid that will need to be converted to extensibility was to hide certain shipping methods based on certain data about the items in the cart, local user time, product tags, metafields etc.
Ideally, I'd show/hide shipping options with our custom carrier app that utilizes the CarrierService API, but the request object Shopify sends to request rates is very sparse, and doesn't seem to have anything in the headers that would allow me to identify the customer's current checkout object to grab any further data from the Admin API. This is especially an issue with providing free shipping based on a dollar value in the cart because Shopify's request object doesn't include any non-physical (non-shippable) item's in the array. We've used Shopify Scripts (also being deprecated) for some of the solutions, otherwise we got a little hackish with checkout.liquid.
I'm looking at using the Delivery Customization API since it seems to be able to do most of what we're looking for as far as hiding shipping methods based on data not provided by Shopify's carrier request.
Question:
If I continue to use our custom app that provides shipping rates to customers in checkout using the Carrier API, will it cause conflicts if I also utilize an extension based on the Delivery Customization Function API? Does the Carrier request happen first, and then the Delivery Customization functions after that?
